# Using bootstrap with Webpack Encore in Symfony 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, symfony4, webpack-encore

I would like to use bootstrap with Webpack Encore in Symfony 4.1 but bootstrap does not function. In the template/base.html.twig file in this post, I used some bootstrap classes but it is not taken into account and I don't understand why.

I installed the dependencies I need for bootstrap with yarn:

```
yarn add bootstrap --dev
yarn add jquery --dev
yarn add popper.js --dev
```

**template/base.html.twig**

In this file, I used the asset function in order to take into account the files: **build/app.scss** and **build/app.js**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/app.scss') }}">
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" ar$
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </nav>

        {% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}
            <script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}"></script>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

In the two following files, I required and imported what I need for bootstrap.

**assets/js/app.js**

```js
require('../css/app.scss');
var $ = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
```

**assets/css/app.scss**

```scss
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

**webpack.config.js**

In this file, I used **enableSassLoader()** in order to activate Sass and **autoProvidejQuery()** in order to have access to jQuery as a global variable.

```js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if you JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

The command **yarn encore dev** builds everything correctly. But, I don't see the bootstrap theme in the screen.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the **template/base.html.twig** file in the head. The result of the global **asset/js/app.scss** in the public/build directory is a **app.css** file and not a .scss extension file. It is the result of the build of all the javascript files we can find in the **assets/js/ directory.**

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/app.css') }}">
    {% endblock %}
</head>
```

Answer (score 6):

Two Twig helpers from WebpackEncoreBundle can do most of the work for you:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#the-import-and-export-statements

```html
{# templates/base.html.twig #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->

        {% block stylesheets %}
            {# 'app' must match the first argument to addEntry() in webpack.config.js #}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}

            <!-- Renders a link tag (if your module requires any CSS)
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/app.css"> -->
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- ... -->

        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}

            <!-- Renders app.js & a webpack runtime.js file
                <script src="/build/runtime.js"></script>
                <script src="/build/app.js"></script> -->
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```