# Unable to properly install and use bootstrap on Symfony 5.3 using Encore

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

As I'm currently working with older Symfony version I started a new 5.3 Symfony app from scratch. I have troubles using bootstrap.
After following up some doc I have installed yarn and :

```
yarn add bootstrap --dev
yarn add node-sass sass-loader --dev
```

Mu base.twig.html have the proper link/script tags :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}

    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
    {% block javascripts %}
        {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}

    {% endblock %}
</html>
```

My app.js :

```
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */


// any CSS you import will output into a single css file (app.css in this case)
import './styles/app.scss';

// start the Stimulus application
import './bootstrap';
```

Also I have app.scss empty and app.css with :

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Is there something else I have omitted ? I have an index.html.twig that has an example form but no css it's rendered:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello IndexController!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
<script>
    console.log('test');
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

`I tried having a look here :

- [Using bootstrap with Webpack Encore in Symfony 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551809/using-bootstrap-with-webpack-encore-in-symfony-4)
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/bootstrap.html
- [Symfony 4 - Webpack Encore bootstrap css not in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54966110/symfony-4-webpack-encore-bootstrap-css-not-in-output)

Comment: Also .enableSassLoader() it's uncommented in webpack.confing.js

Answer (score 2):

Solved: @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap'; was inside app.css, after moving it to app.scss it worked